# Sort the array of database object-id

Tags: javascript, mongodb, sorting

I have a array of mongodb object-id and i want to sort them in such a way that similar IDs are next to each other

**example** :

Input :

`var array = ["507f191e810c19729de860ea","00000020f51bb4362eee2a4d",” 507f191e810c19729de860ea”]`

Output :

`var array = ["507f191e810c19729de860ea","507f191e810c19729de860ea","00000020f51bb4362eee2a4d"]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply sorting the input array would result in the same input array being sorted in natural order (converting the input to a `string`, if needed, and comparing the elements UTF-16 code units):

```
array.sort();
```

In case you would want the reverse order, you can `reverse` the array:

```
array.sort().reverse();
```